# Restful web service to take complex object as input

Tags: java, web-services, object

How can i pass a complex object like Person class as an input parameter in restful web service??

I have gone through many links but didnt find the solution. Please help

Comment: Use JSON-RPC instead

Answer (score 0):

Transform the object into JSON or XML (or any other format, but these are the most common), and send it into the body of the request.

Comment: Any other way of sending the data because i have worked on SOAP and there i can send any complex type of object as input..So looking if there is any other similar type of thing in REST...

Comment: SOAP does exactly what I told: it transforms inputs into XML. Just use a JSON or XML serializer. There are dozens of these: Jackson, Gson, JAXB, etc. Some client REST apis do the serialization for you.

Answer (score 0):

There are Restful Client api's available in java

1.JAX-RS-API-->JersyImpl,Resteasy(Jboss) Impl etc

You can use any of these and can pass any java object as input to restful resource.

Comment: i am new to restful webserice..can you please share a link or some code snippet..that will be indeed helpful.. Thanks in advance...